# Regex over multiple lines with \n

Tags: python-3.x, regex

In the following code I would like to capture the instance ID and then the body underneath it. The pattern is recurring so that there are multiple instances with the same bodies.  I can't seem to figure out how to get it to continue past the newline segments.

```
import re

config = '''
Instance: evpn-a

VLAN ID: 123, MAC address: 00:05:86:71:05:f0
  Source: irb.0, Rank: 1, Status: Active
    State: <Local-MAC-Only Local-Gateway Remote-Adv-Allowed>
    IP address: 192.168.10.251

VLAN ID: 123, MAC address: 00:05:86:71:ab:f0
  Source: 20.1.1.2, Rank: 1, Status: Active
    State: <Remote-Gateway Local-Adv-Allowed Local-Adv-Done>
    IP address: 192.168.10.252
      L3 route: 192.168.10.252/32, L3 context: bridge-vrf (irb.0)

Instance: evpn-b

VLAN ID: 123, MAC address: 00:05:86:71:05:f0
  Source: irb.0, Rank: 1, Status: Active
    State: <Local-MAC-Only Local-Gateway Remote-Adv-Allowed>
    IP address: 192.168.10.251

VLAN ID: 123, MAC address: 00:05:86:71:ab:f0
  Source: 20.1.1.2, Rank: 1, Status: Active
    State: <Remote-Gateway Local-Adv-Allowed Local-Adv-Done>
    IP address: 192.168.10.252
      L3 route: 192.168.10.252/32, L3 context: bridge-vrf (irb.0)
'''


evpn_obj_list = re.compile(r'Instance:\s+(\S+)(.*?)(?:\S+|\Z)',re.S|re.M).findall(config)

evpn = evpn_obj_list

print(evpn)
```

The result I get from the above is:

```
[('evpn-a', '\n\n'), ('evpn-b', '\n\n')]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
rx = re.compile(r'^Instance:\s+(\S+)\s*(.*?)(?=\n\s*Instance:\s|\Z)', re.S|re.M)
evpn_obj_list = rx.findall(config)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UNSyVB/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line
- `Instance:` - a string
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(\S+)` - Group 1: any one or more non-whitespace chars
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any 0 or more chars, as few as possible
- `(?=\n\s*Instance:\s|\Z)` - a positive lookahead that requires a newline, 0+ whitespaces, `Instance:`, a whitespace OR the end of file immediately to the right of the current location.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/9myOhB) yielding

```
[('evpn-a', 'VLAN ID: 123, MAC address: 00:05:86:71:05:f0\n  Source: irb.0, Rank: 1, Status: Active\n    State: <Local-MAC-Only Local-Gateway Remote-Adv-Allowed>\n    IP address: 192.168.10.251\n\nVLAN ID: 123, MAC address: 00:05:86:71:ab:f0\n  Source: 20.1.1.2, Rank: 1, Status: Active\n    State: <Remote-Gateway Local-Adv-Allowed Local-Adv-Done>\n    IP address: 192.168.10.252\n      L3 route: 192.168.10.252/32, L3 context: bridge-vrf (irb.0)'), ('evpn-b', 'VLAN ID: 123, MAC address: 00:05:86:71:05:f0\n  Source: irb.0, Rank: 1, Status: Active\n    State: <Local-MAC-Only Local-Gateway Remote-Adv-Allowed>\n    IP address: 192.168.10.251\n\nVLAN ID: 123, MAC address: 00:05:86:71:ab:f0\n  Source: 20.1.1.2, Rank: 1, Status: Active\n    State: <Remote-Gateway Local-Adv-Allowed Local-Adv-Done>\n    IP address: 192.168.10.252\n      L3 route: 192.168.10.252/32, L3 context: bridge-vrf (irb.0)\n')]
```